# Trouble with API based on JSON-RPC 2.0

Tags: php, json, api, json-rpc

I am trying to connect to an API which is based on JSON-RPC 2.0. As i am new to this im not sure if im coding this correctly because all I am recieving is an error.

Can anyone give me a brief explanation on how to connect to API in PHP?

```
<?php
 header('Content-Type: application/json');
 //check if you have curl loaded
 if(!function_exists("curl_init")) die("cURL extension is not installed");

 $url = 'xxxxxxxxx';

$data = array(
"operator_id" => "xxxx",
"login"       => "xxxx",
"password"    => "xxxx",
);

$curl_options = array(
     CURLOPT_URL => $url,
     CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
     CURLOPT_NOBODY => true,
     CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
     CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
     CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
     CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
     CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'gzip,deflate',
     CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT    => true,
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curl_options);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$arr = json_decode($output,true);
echo ($output);
?>
```

The response i am recieving is this: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"Invalid request"},"id":null}

The response i should be recieving if successful login is: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":true,"error":null,"id":1,"ts":1368533487}

Comment: Please, give add an example of code which is not working correctly.

Comment: Just included the code and errors...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not sending a JSON-RPC request at all.

The request must be a JSON body, so you must json_encode the data before passing it to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.

The posted json must have the keys `method`, `params`, `id`, and `jsonrpc` (the last should be set to "2.0").  Your data would go into `params`.  The `id` can be set to whatever, but without it you shouldn't get a response at all.

It is a quite simple format.  See the specification at http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification

Comment: Thanks mate! Ive just realised what i was trying to sent... Im not getting the correct response! Cheers again.